# character of a finite group where characteristic of field F not equal to 0.

Tags: gr.group-theory

Why is it that if characteristic of the field F is not equal to 0 then the constant function 0 is an F-character of a finite group G?

Comment: This is not true as stated. It is also probably not appropriate for this site. Maybe try math.stackexchange.com 

Comment: It's the character of a zero-dimensional representation!

Comment: Raja -- a hint: take a set on which the group acts freely and another, with $char(F)$ elements, on which the group acts trivially.

Comment: It's also the character of the sum of $p$ copies of any representation, where $p$ is the characteristic of $F$.